# How to bin on timeframe with pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, binning

I have following (oversimplified) dataset :

| userid | program_id | program_start | program_end | viewing_start | viewing_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | 2023-01-01 00:05:00 | 2023-01-01 00:50:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | 2023-01-01 00:20:00 | 2023-01-01 00:25:00 |

and what I like to receive is like follows

| userid | program_id | program_start | program_end | viewing_start | viewing_end | start_bin | end_bin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | 2023-01-01 00:05:00 | 2023-01-01 00:50:00 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | 2023-01-01 00:20:00 | 2023-01-01 00:25:00 | 2 | 2 |

Where I have my users (userid) watching a specific asset (program_id) and each asset has a defined duration (program_start to program_end time). Users can start and end watching this whenever they want, for how long they want as long as it is between program_start and program_end

What I want to do is bin / bucketize my assets, lets say into 4 buckets. That's still easy to achieve but next I want to understand in which of these bins the user started watching the asset.

So if an asset runs from midnight to 1 AM, and a user starts watching at 10 past midnight he fits in the first bucket (or basically started watching in the first quarter).

I'm kind of struggling to achieve this with pyspark, so any advice on how to tackle this without consuming all my resources would be helpfull.

Not really looking for full blown copy/paste solutions, just some friendly advice and guidance in the right direction is probably be enough to get me moving on.

Answer (score 1):

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T, functions as F
df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([{"userid":0,"program_id":1,"program_start":"2023-01-01 00:00:00","program_end":"2023-01-01 01:00:00","viewing_start":"2023-01-01 00:05:00","viewing_end":"2023-01-01 00:50:00"},{"userid":1,"program_id":1,"program_start":"2023-01-01 00:00:00","program_end":"2023-01-01 01:00:00","viewing_start":"2023-01-01 00:20:00","viewing_end":"2023-01-01 00:25:00"}]), schema=T.StructType([
    T.StructField('user_id', T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('program_id', T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('program_start', T.TimestampType()),
    T.StructField('program_end', T.TimestampType()),
    T.StructField('viewing_start', T.TimestampType()),
    T.StructField('viewing_end', T.TimestampType())
]))

df.withColumn(
    'bucket_duration', 
    ((F.col('program_end') - F.col('program_start')) / 60).cast('int') / 4
).withColumn(
    'start_offset', 
    ((F.col('viewing_start') - F.col('program_start')) / 60).cast('int')
).withColumn(
    'end_offset', 
    ((F.col('viewing_end') - F.col('program_start')) / 60).cast('int')
).withColumn(
    'start_bucket',
    F.ceil(F.col('start_offset') / F.col('bucket_duration'))
).withColumn(
    'end_bucket',
    F.ceil(F.col('end_offset') / F.col('bucket_duration'))
).display()
```

|  | user_id | program_id | program_start | program_end | viewing_start | viewing_end | bucket_duration | start_offset | end_offset | start_bucket | end_bucket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | 2023-01-01 00:05:00 | 2023-01-01 00:50:00 | 15 | 5 | 50 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | 2023-01-01 00:20:00 | 2023-01-01 00:25:00 | 15 | 20 | 25 | 2 | 2 |

The process is pretty simple, and it works assuming viewing end isn't later then program end.

We calculate the program duration, then see how long since the start of the program the user started/ended watching, divide that by the bucket duration (total duration / 4 buckets) and you get the start and end bucket.

It can be done with less "withColumns" but I added them to make it clear what happens.

It needs to be tweaked a bit to support starting at the exact time or really short programs, but you asked for a general idea :)

Answer (score 1):

you could also use array for this - get the bin length in seconds and create the bins in an array of struct.

here's an example

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('window_secs', (func.col('prog_end') - func.col('prog_start')).cast('long') / 4). \
    withColumn('ts_arr', func.array_repeat(func.col('prog_start').cast('long'), 4)). \
    withColumn('ts_arr', 
               func.expr('''transform(ts_arr, 
                                      (x, i) -> struct(i+1 as win, 
                                                       cast(x + i*window_secs as timestamp) as win_start, 
                                                       cast(x + (i+1)*window_secs as timestamp) as win_end
                                                       )
                                      )
                         ''')
               ). \
    withColumn('view_start_win', func.filter('ts_arr', lambda x: func.col('view_start').between(x.win_start, x.win_end))[0]). \
    withColumn('view_start_win', func.col('view_start_win.win')). \
    withColumn('view_end_win', func.filter('ts_arr', lambda x: func.col('view_end').between(x.win_start, x.win_end))[0]). \
    withColumn('view_end_win', func.col('view_end_win.win')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+
# |usrid|progid|prog_start         |prog_end           |view_start         |view_end           |window_secs|ts_arr                                                                                                                                                                                      |view_start_win|view_end_win|
# +-----+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+
# |0    |1     |2023-01-01 00:00:00|2023-01-01 01:00:00|2023-01-01 00:05:00|2023-01-01 00:50:00|900.0      |[{1, 2023-01-01 00:00:00, 2023-01-01 00:15:00}, {2, 2023-01-01 00:15:00, 2023-01-01 00:30:00}, {3, 2023-01-01 00:30:00, 2023-01-01 00:45:00}, {4, 2023-01-01 00:45:00, 2023-01-01 01:00:00}]|1             |4           |
# |1    |1     |2023-01-01 00:00:00|2023-01-01 01:00:00|2023-01-01 00:20:00|2023-01-01 00:25:00|900.0      |[{1, 2023-01-01 00:00:00, 2023-01-01 00:15:00}, {2, 2023-01-01 00:15:00, 2023-01-01 00:30:00}, {3, 2023-01-01 00:30:00, 2023-01-01 00:45:00}, {4, 2023-01-01 00:45:00, 2023-01-01 01:00:00}]|2             |2           |
# +-----+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+
```